# how to add node in xml before any perticular node in java

Tags: java, xml, xsd

My existing xml file looks like

```
<transaction>
  <id>
    <in>computer</in>
    <sn>1234567</sn>
    <book>JAVA</book>
    <author>klen</author>
  </id>
  <data>
    <dateTime>2011-06-24T17:08:36.3727674+05:30</dateTime>
    <key>Err</key>
  </data>
</transaction>
```

but I want to add node before `<id>` node.Now I have 2 question
1.Using dom perser how to add node before ?
2.Is it possible to do this other than dom parser?because I give a demo xml original xml is large so I need a good parser for better performance.

I want to add this

```
       <xs:schema id="transaction" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">  
    <xs:element name="transaction" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">  
      <xs:complexType>  
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">  
          <xs:element name="id">  
            <xs:complexType>  
              <xs:sequence>  
                <xs:element name="in" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />  
                <xs:element name="sn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />  
                <xs:element name="book" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />  
                <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />  
               </xs:sequence>  
            </xs:complexType>  
          </xs:element>  
          <xs:element name="data">  
            <xs:complexType>  
              <xs:sequence>  
                <xs:element name="dateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />  
                <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />  
              </xs:sequence>  
            </xs:complexType>  
          </xs:element>  
          <xs:element name="productData">  
            <xs:complexType>  
              <xs:sequence>  
                <xs:element name="dateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />  
                <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />  
              </xs:sequence>  
            </xs:complexType>  
          </xs:element>  
        </xs:choice>  
      </xs:complexType>  
    </xs:element>  
  </xs:schema>
```

before `<id>` node under `<transaction>` node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1:  "Using dom perser how to add node before ?"

Answer 1:
I assume that you are using [org.w3c.dom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html#package_description).  Let `node1` be a [Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) in your document.  Let `node2` be another [Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) in your document.  You want to [insert node1 before node2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#insertBefore%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20org.w3c.dom.Node%29).

Question 2: "Is it possible to do this other than dom parser?"

Answer 2: DOM is not the current state of the art with respect to XML.  You should look into XSLT, SAX, and or JAXB.

Comment: Actually I generate this xml file using JAXB,now I want to add inline xml schema within it under <transaction> node before <id> node but I can node do that using JAXB because jaxb does not provide any method by which I can add inline schema when I do the marshaling.So I generate xml file first then I write the file again to add the inline schema.I am new in java can you give some code snips by which I can add node before <id> node.

Comment: here I add node before <id> using this code TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transFactory.newTransformer();
Element staffElement = doc.createElement("staff");
Node updateText = doc.createTextNode("fgdsf");
staffElement.appendChild(updateText);
System.out.println(root.getElementsByTagName("id"));
root.insertBefore(staffElement,root.getFirstChild());
transformer.transform(source, result);  but I can not formated it can you help me.

Comment: how can I do that using Jaxb?